# Alert using the select object

Tags: javascript

I have tried using the select object with JavaScript but it dosent seem to be going.  do anyone know what am talking about

this is what I have tried

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;

var u = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=u;
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  What does your code do?  What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");  //reference the select
var index = sel.selectedIndex;  //find the index that was picked
var option = sel.options[index];  //select the option that was picked
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = option.value;  //read the value
```

if you want the text and not the value use .text

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = option.text;  //read the value
```

What this sample code does not do is deal if nothing is selected. That would be a selectedIndex equal to -1.

Comment: Or just `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sel.value;`.